# Multiple access_keys for different privileges with same S3 account?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a single S3/AWS account. I have several websites each which use their own bucket on S3 for reading/writing storage. I also host a lot of personal stuff (backups, etc) on other buckets on S3, which are not publicly accessible.

I would like to not have these websites-- some of which may have other people accessing their source code and configuration properties and seeing the S3 keys-- having access to my private data!

It seems from reading Amazon's docs that I need to partition privileges, by Amazon *USER* per bucket, not by access key per bucket. But that's not going to work. It also seems like I only get 2 access keys. I need to have one access key which is the master key, and several others which have much more circumscribed permissions-- only for certain buckets.

Is there any way to do that, or to approximate that?

Comment: Have you looked into Amazon IAM?  There's a link right off the AWS console.  You can control the permissions with incredible precision and generate as many access keys as you want, even temporary ones.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve your goal by facilitating [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/):

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) enables you to **securely
>   control access to AWS services and resources** for your users. IAM
>   enables you to create and manage users in AWS, and it also enables you
>   to grant access to AWS resources for users managed outside of AWS in
>   your corporate directory. **IAM offers greater security, flexibility,
>   and control when using AWS.** *[emphasis mine]*

As emphasized, using IAM is strongly recommended for all things AWS anyway, i.e. ideally you should never use your main account credentials for anything but setting up IAM initially (as [mentioned by Judge Mental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729322/multiple-access-keys-for-different-privileges-with-same-s3-account/10733367#comment13940830_10729322) already, you can *generate as many access keys as you want* like so).

You can use IAM just fine via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#iam) (i.e. their is no need for 3rd party tools to use all available functionality in principle).

Generating the required policies can be a bit tricky in times, but the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) is extremely helpful to get you started and explore what's available.

For the use case at hand you'll need a *S3 Bucket Policy*, see [Using Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html) in particular and [Access Control](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html) for a general overview of the various available S3 access control mechanisms (which can interfere in subtle ways, see e.g. [Using ACLs and Bucket Policies Together](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingACLsandBucketPoliciesTogether.html)).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, To access different login account with different permission using same AWS Account, you can use AWS IAM. As a developer of Bucket Explorer, I am suggesting try Bucket Explorer- team edition if you are looking for the tool provide you gui interface with different login and different access permission. read http://team20.bucketexplorer.com

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a custom IAM group policy that limits access to a particular bucket

**Such as...**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource":
      [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The first action `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` allows the users to list all of the buckets. Without that, their S3 client will show nothing in the bucket listing when the users logon.

The second action grants full S3 privileges to the user for the bucket named 'my.bucket'. That means they're free to create/list/delete bucket resources and user ACLs within the bucket.

Granting s3:* access is pretty lax. If you want tighter controls on the bucket just look up the relevant actions you want to grant and add them as a list.

```
"Action": "s3:Lists3:GetObject, s3:PutObject, s3:DeleteObject"
```

I suggest you create this policy as a group (ex my.bucket_User) so you can assign it to every user who needs access to this bucket without any unnecessary copypasta.